# Change color of a dojo tab pane

Tags: dojo, xpages, tabcontainer

How do I change the color title of a dojo tab pane of a dojo tab container in a xpage under a given condition? Could anyone give me a roadmap on how to change the label's color?

Comment: it's always better to post what have you tried so far so that others can help you

Comment: right click the tab in Chrome and choose inspect. look for the class name used to set the color and override it,

Comment: Just use CSS and override the style for the tab in "the given condition". But for a real answer you should edit your question and let us know what you mean exactly and what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, and hide the style panel based on your condition

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">

    <xp:panel tagName="style">
    div.dijitTab:nth-child(1){background-color:red !important}
    </xp:panel>

    <xp:panel style="padding:30px">
    <xe:djTabContainer id="djTabContainer1">
        <xe:djTabPane id="djTabPane1" title="Tab1">1</xe:djTabPane>
        <xe:djTabPane id="djTabPane2" title="Tab2">2</xe:djTabPane>
    </xe:djTabContainer>
    </xp:panel>
</xp:view>
```

[image]

Comment: The problem that the application runs in IE with version 7 compatibility mode, there your code does not work. Can you only execute this section in a compatible compatibility mode with its operation?

Comment: http://www.intec.co.uk/compatibility-mode-what-any-xpages-or-web-developer-needs-to-know/